# python "too many to unpack" when unpacking a tuple returned by a function

Tags: python, function, dataframe, null, apply

I was trying to apply a function to one of the columns in a dataframe, and the function returns three items. For some cases, it works but for other cases it doesn't work. Then I realized it's probably because of the existent of the NULL values. So here's the simplified version of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
def proc(x):
    return ([x,1,2], [x+1,3,4], [x+2,5,6])

## This works fine.
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3]})
df['new1'],df['new2'], df['new3'] = df.a.apply(lambda x:proc(x))

## But this throws the 'too many values to unpack' error.
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3, float('nan')]})
df2['new1'],df2['new2'], df2['new3'] = df2.a.apply(lambda x:proc(x))
```

Why adding the float('nan') into the column of `df['a']` can cause this error?

Comment: `nan` is still a value

Comment: Why not simply `proc` instead of `lambda x: proc(x)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `zip` to pack the values:

   ```
   def proc(x):
       return ([x,1,2], [x+1,3,4], [x+2,5,6])

   df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,4, float('nan')]})
   df2['new1'], df2['new2'], df2['new3'] = zip(*df2['a'].apply(proc))

        a      new1         new2        new3
     0 1.0 [1.0, 1, 2] [2.0, 3, 4] [3.0, 5, 6]
     1 2.0 [2.0, 1, 2] [3.0, 3, 4] [4.0, 5, 6]
     2 4.0 [4.0, 1, 2] [5.0, 3, 4] [6.0, 5, 6]
     3 NaN [nan, 1, 2] [nan, 3, 4] [nan, 5, 6]
   ```
2. Use the right number of list elements to unpack and equal number to return in proc:

   ```
   def proc(x):
       return ([x,1,2], [x+1,3,4], [x+2,5,6])

   df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,4, float('nan')]})
   df2['new1'], df2['new2'], df2['new3'] = zip(*df2['a'].apply(proc))

        a  new1         new2        new3        new4
   0   1.0 [1.0, 1, 2] [2.0, 1, 2] [4.0, 1, 2] [nan, 1, 2]
   1   2.0 [2.0, 3, 4] [3.0, 3, 4] [5.0, 3, 4] [nan, 3, 4]
   2   4.0 [3.0, 5, 6] [4.0, 5, 6] [6.0, 5, 6] [nan, 5, 6]
   3   NaN [4.0, 7, 8] [5.0, 7, 8] [7.0, 7, 8] [nan, 7, 8]
   ```

Comment: Thanks @Mokshyam. It seems that the `apply` is not carried out as what I have (mistakenly) understood. I thought for each `x` in `df2['a']`, the function returns three lists, and I can just assign them to the three new columns - so no matter how many elements are in 'df2['a']`, the code could work. Apparently that is not the case....But how can I do that?